# qt creator under linux, how to debug

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am using qt creator under linux with GDB.
I found even if I write really dumb error like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    int *a;
    a[12]=1;
    ...
}
```

The program do crash as expected, but unlike under Windows (I use Visual Studio a lot in the past). I did not really find the program 'stop' at the crashing line, nor anywhere tells me which line crashes the program.

When it crash, there is just an application output says: `Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-load.c: 2325: _dl_map_object: Assertion nsid < _rtld_local._dl_nns failed!` The application just exit, instead of stop and let me get a call stack.

How could I tell which line crashes my program under qtcreator?

Comment: Well, where does it stop? What's the stack trace? You should see `main` on the stack trace and see where the execution ended there. Furthermore, this code is not guaranteed to crash reliably. You might be better served by calling `abort()` explicitly, and setting a breakpoint there.

Comment: When it crash, there is just an application output says: "Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-load.c: 2325: _dl_map_object: Assertion `nsid < _rtld_local._dl_nns' failed!" The application just exit, instead of stop and let me get a call stack. BTW, the abort() do stops the program. But under visual studio2013, the program actually crashes whenever it reaches a[12]=1 ?

Comment: How do you start your app from Qt Creator? There are 2 buttons, one starts app under debugger, another one as external app w/o debugger. This is unlike VS, which by default launches app in debugging mode

Comment: I do enter through the debugger...

Comment: and can you stop at breakpoint at `a[12]=1;` line?

Comment: Yes, I can stop at any line without problem.

Comment: So most likely the crash happens not in the code being debugged. You `a[12]=1;` corrupts something in library (probably in `ld.so`) and causes (a little bit later) crash

Comment: See what happens if you initialize `int *a = 0;`

Comment: It might be a gdb bug or Qt Creator bug. Open the debug console and see the output. See if you can reproduce this issue by running the debugger from the command line.